# double (or triple) curly braces in netbeans (e.g Blade Templates)

Tags: netbeans

This is strange. I have set my background to black and now when I type double braces in netBeans they both becomes black (and thus invisible as the background is also black)

Hers is an example:

```
 <title>{{}}</title>
```

The title in-between becomes all black. Where in NetBean is responsible for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to `Tools -> Options`
2. Select `Font & Color`
3. For Language, select HTML
4. Select `Text` from `Category`
5. Change the color of the text to a more visible color

Another option is, in the same Options dialog, just change the `profile`. It will give you predefined settings, so you don't have to mess with each category individually, which sometimes is hard to keep track of and maintain.

**EDIT**

Change the foreground of `Expression Delimiter` category. I tested it, and it works and maybe `Expression Content`, depending on your current settings. You my also need to change `Text`

Comment: no this is not the solution. Since it shows text and strings, it also shows curly braces, but when curly braces are grouped in two or three or more, they become balck

Comment: Is there a reference guide that does a good job of describing which color setting a particular element uses?  I never would have found this on my own.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Go to Tools -> Options
> 2. Select Font & Color
> 3. For Language, select HTML
> 4. Select "Expression Delimiters" from Category
> 5. Set Foreground color to white(if your IDE's background if white). In short, it should be easily visible color when comparing with IDE's
>      background color.

[image]